# Extracting the numbers of two elements which their sum is equal to their multiplication

Tags: python, list, input, analytics, data-handling

we have array A that has N len(N = the len of the array)
I have to found the numbers of pairs (J, I) that work on the following statement:

```
A[J]+A[I} == A[J] * A[I]
```

1<=i, j<=N

(1 ≤ N ≤ 40000)

(0 ≤ A(i) ≤ 10^9)

### example:

input:

```
3
2 4 2
```

output:

```
1
```

well i counldn't know how to limit the input size to only have 2 spaces or to split it if there was any more than the N

edit*

```py
A = []
N = int(input(""))
B = (input(""))

B = B.split()
z = 0
myList = []
mylist2= []
pairs = 0
for q in B:
    if z < N:
        myList.append(q)
        z += 1
    elif z >= N:
        break

for w in myList:
    w = int(w)
    mylist2.append(w)

for i in mylist2:
    for k in mylist2:`enter code here`
        if i + k == i * k:
            pairs+1
```

that what i have done so far

Comment: sorry @Mosaab looks like home work question to me

Comment: it was on a test today and i couldnt figure it out

Comment: well i need the numbers of these pairs if they were repeated like 2 ,2 ,2 ,2

Comment: i have edited the question and added what i have done

Comment: anything yet?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as already mentioned in comments only pairs `(2, 2)` and `(0, 0)` satisfy the condition. The number of `(0, 0)` pairs is `count(0) * (count(0) - 1) / 2`. The same for `(2, 2)` pairs. Expressing this in python (assuming that array `a` is given).

```
def countsumprod(a):
    c0 = a.count(0)
    c2 = a.count(2)
    return (c0 * (c0 - 1) + c2 * (c2 - 1)) // 2
```

Comment: yes thats works

Comment: but how that works?

Comment: @MosaabBarghouthy What exactly is not clear?